# In the Office addin manifest, does Outlook for Mac support v1.5/1.6?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

According to the compatibility table, version 1.5 and 1.6 of the Javascript API for Office is compatible with Outlook for Mac 2016.

I am on version 16.16 (180812) for Outlook for Mac. When I set the minimum version to either 1.5 or 1.6, my addin fails to install.

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
        <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.5" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Any insight here?

Errors that I receive when trying to install... FYI, the manifest I'm using passes with the office-addin-validation tool

[image: This is the message when trying the first time.]
[image: The second and every subsequent try. The text just just spits out my manifest.]

**Update:** After going through the install several times, I am able to install with v1.5 some of the time. I get the "installation takes longer than expected message" once and no error on another try.
v1.6 still does not install at all.

Comment: Can you share the error which you get during install? I was able to install an add-in with 1.5 version

Comment: @SureshGowthamS images added.

Comment: The error text in the image is not useful, but in my case 1.6 version of add-in fails with "installation takes longer than expected message" and never shows up in mac. But it actually showed up in Outlook for Web & Windows. I think the installation succeeded but Outlook for mac has a bug.

Comment: I came across the same issue. While I though I had been able to install an addon with v1.6 on Mac with a previous version I'm not able to do that any more. I'm also on 16.16. Unfortunately I cannot downgrade to try again with an earlier version.